# How to ignore outer/parent element until breaking point

Tags: html, css, parent-child

I was wondering how to ignore the div tag in this bit of code until a certain screen size is reached (767px) but still display everything inside.

```
<div class="parent">
    <h4 class"title">Title</h4>
    <ul>
        <li>Cities</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "ignore the div tag"?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use Javascript.

Why do you not remove only the class of the element? Like this:

```js
var parentClass = 'parent';

if ($(window).width() >= 767) {
  var p = $('.parent');
  p.removeClass('parent');
} else {
  p.addClass('parent');
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <h4 class "title">Title</h4>
  <ul>
    <li>Cities</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure what you mean by ignore but still display everything inside, so this may not be exactly what you're looking for. However, I would detect screen size and change using JQuery events, and adjust the display accordingly. For example:

```
function ShowHideParent() {
    if($(window).width() >= 768 && $(window).height >= 480)
        $('.parent').show();
    else
        $('.parent').hide();
}

$(document).ready( function () {
    ShowHideParent();
});
$(window).resize( function () {
    ShowHideParent();
});
```

If you elaborate more on exactly what you want and why, we might be able to find a better solution. I have a feeling that you might be using this as a workaround for small displays such as the ones on mobile devices. If that is the case, then you may be interested in checking out a web front-end framework such as [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/). These frameworks have taken care of a lot of the hassle of accommodating a variety of screen sizes, and can help display your content cleanly without having to resort to hacky workarounds.